# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes on boot after Windows 10 update

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Just installed most recent Windows 10 updates alongside Ubuntu 16.04 and when I switched back to Ubuntu 16.04, all it would do was display the Ubuntu logo and dots for a few seconds and then freeze. Tried all of the advanced options in grub2 (barring recovery) after which it went a bit longer before it froze. What should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

Check the bios has not been switched back to secure mode, this can problems with some nvidia graphics chips.

Comment: BIOS is not in secure mode, and after I checked on that, I tried restarting my laptop (an Asus X202E Vivobook) again to see what would happen. No dice.